# Linking to a particular tab in a URL

Tags: html, django

I'd like to link to a particular tab on a page through a URL. Is this possible without using Jquery (which I have basically no knowledge in)?

Here is my HTML. I want the link to open the YouTube tab.

```
<div class="tabbable span12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><h3> Videos including YouTube links </h3></li>
        <li class="pull-right">
            <a href="#YouTube" data-toggle="tab">YouTube</a>
        </li>
    <li class="active pull-right">
            <a href="#Newest" data-toggle="tab">Newest</a>
        </li>
```

Just say my link is: "/stuff/videos". How can I link to the YouTube tab on this page in the *easiest* way.

I tried "/stuff/videos#YouTube" but this did not work.

BTW I'm using the Django framework if that changes anything.

Update: Here's the code that instantiates the tab. I'm using Bootstrap.

```
        <div class="tab-pane" id="YouTube">
```

Comment: How is the YouTube tab hidden? I'm afraid you need to be a little clearer in what you're trying to achieve. Try posting all of your HTML markup.

Comment: A LI tag is not a tab unless you use somekind of functionality to redefine it. Maybe your requested functionality is already defined in that code? Post your relevant code here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onclick` JS handler for tab link to switch to a tab dynamically, and check `location.hash` on page load to switch to corresponding tab automatically.

Comment: Ok let me try this out and will submit as answered if it works. Thanks!